# How to hold navigation screen on swipe both push and pop view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on `swipe gesture` and want to hold `navigation controller` for both while push and pop view controller.  This is working well while using pop view controller but not hold `navigation controller` while pushing view controller. Is there any solution for this?

My sample code is below.

```
//MARK:- Swipe
    func swipeGestures() {
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(fromGesture:)))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(fromGesture:)))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    }

    //MARK:- Swipe Method
    @objc func dismiss(fromGesture gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.direction == .left{
            pushOnSwipe("SecondVC", false)
        } else {
            pushOnSwipe("ThirdVC", true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `pushOnSwipe` method do? I notice that for `gesture.direction == .right` you call it with `true`. Could this be the issue? Also what do you mean by hold? Keep the VC in memory or stay on the current one?